# Can't access Log in ArangoDB Web Interface 3.11.x?

Tags: arangodb

I've just upgraded to ArangoDB 3.11.x and I can't find log anywhere. Well actually, I can still see in in `_system` DB but when I go to a specific database, the Logs tab is gone. Does anyone know how to get Logs back or do I need to revert back to 3.10.x?

First image is _system where I can see the log. The second one is in a specific database where it seems to have disappeared.

[image]

[image: 3.11.x DB no log]